# write values of dictionary in separate csv columns and create headers

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have created a dictionary that uses date as the key and added multiple values to each date. The dictionary is populated by reading an original csv so that I can create totals per date.

My Code:

```
import csv

##Opens the csv file to be read
tradedata=open("test.csv","r")

##Reads the csv file
tradedatareader = csv.reader(tradedata,delimiter=',',quotechar='"')

##create dictionary
my_dict = {}
for row in tradedatareader:
 Date = row[1][0:8]
 volume = int(row[4])
 price = float(row[5])
 Transtype=row[6]
 ##Find SEC_Fee
 if Transtype !="BUY":
    ttype =1
 else:
    ttype=0
 secfee=(ttype*volume*price*.0000221)

##Finds Notional Value
 notional_val = (volume*price)

##Finds Clearing Fees
 cl_fee = (volume*.0005)

 if cl_fee < .05:
     clearing_fee = 0.05
 else:
     clearing_fee = (volume*.0005)
##Finds Totals per Date
 my_dict[Date] = my_dict.setdefault(Date, [0,0,0,0,0]) 
 my_dict[Date][0] = my_dict[Date][0] + volume
 my_dict[Date][1] = my_dict[Date][1] + notional_val
 my_dict[Date][2] = my_dict[Date][2] + secfee
 my_dict[Date][3] = my_dict[Date][3] + clearing_fee
 my_dict[Date][4] = my_dict[Date][4] + secfee + clearing_fee

## Writes totals to CSV
with open('mycsvfile.csv','w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
    w.writerows(my_dict.items())
```

This currently writes the key in column A and the values in column B and skips a line between each row.

I would like each value to be written in its own column and would like each column to have a header like this:

```
DATE      Volume    Notional Value       SEC FEES     Clearing Fees      Total Fees   
20140612   2751       157750.56       3.4132565999     1.4500000          4.8632566
20140612   5148       270200.02       5.831338266      2.692499999        8.523838265999998
```

Comment: I'm not sure why your post was down voted, but I will up-vote it because I think it is valuable.

Comment: On another note, I would suggest naming your variables as lower-cased with underscores between them. Example: `Date` should become `date`. That will make your code readable w.r.t. Pythonic conventions.

Comment: I'd guess the downvote is because there's much more code here than necessary to solve the question asked. Agreed, a useful question though.

Comment: I am brand new to Python just started looking at it on Monday for a project I was assigned. I thank you very much for your words of encouragement.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using Pandas.

If you set up your data as a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary represents a row, and the keys of the dictionary are the columns with the values being the row values, then when you do:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(list_of_dictionaries).to_csv('put_your_filename_here.csv')
```

you should have the data formatted correctly.

Comment: You can also read in the data using `pandas.read_csv('test.csv')` which might make the whole process easier and avoid going via dictionaries at all.

Comment: Ah yes! Totally did not spot that point in the OP's post - that the data came from a CSV file itself.

Answer (score 0):

The items() returns a list of key, values, which is not what you want to write to the file. This code works:

```
with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(['DATE', 'Volume', 'Notional Value', 'SEC FEES', 'Clearing Fees', 'Total Fees'])
    for date in sorted(my_dict):
        w.writerow([date] + my_dict[date])
```

If you don't want the output sorted, just remove the sorted() function.

Comment: This actually worked perfectly; however I still have empty rows in between each populated row. Is there a way to remove those empty rows?

Comment: Since I don't know what your data looks like, I have no idea how to deal with it. You can help by updating your post with input data.